# Table margins in the article

Tags: tables, margins, size

I have the following table:

[image]

I have the following questions:

1. Is there any way to force the table to be the same width as the
   article text?
2. And also force all columns to be the same size?
3. Also, force the table to be only on one page, without overlapping
   with the page number?

Code:

```
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcommand{\tilt}[2][14em]{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{\parbox{#1}{\raggedleft #2}}}
\noindent\begin{table}
\FloatBarrier
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |P{12em}| |C|C|C| |C|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|C| }

    \hline
    \textbf{Paper(s)} &
    \multicolumn{3}{|c||}{\textbf{Data Sources}} &
    \multicolumn{9}{|c||}{\textbf{Technique}} \\

    \cline{2-13}
    &
    \tilt{\textbf{Log-based}} &
    \tilt{\textbf{Distributed Tracing-based}} &
    \tilt{\textbf{Monitoring-Based}} &
    \tilt{\textbf{Unsupervised learning}} &
    \tilt{\textbf{Supervised learning}} &
    \tilt{\textbf{Reinforcement learning}} &
    \tilt{\textbf{Semi-supervised learning}} &
    \tilt{\textbf{Statistical Approach}} &
    \tilt{\textbf{Causal Inference}} &
    \tilt{\textbf{Trace comparison}} &
    \tilt{\textbf{HeartBeating}} &
    \tilt{\textbf{SLO checks}} \\

    \hline
    \cite{liu2020unsupervised, nedelkoski2019anomaly, vallis2014novel, pahl2018all, jin2020anomaly, bogatinovski2020self} &
    &  % Log-based
    \textbullet &   % Distributed Tracing-based
    &   % Monitoring-Based
    \textbullet &   % Unsupervised learning
    &   % Supervised learning
    &   % Reinforcement learning
    &   % Semi-supervised learning
    &   % Statistical Approach
    &   % Causal Inference
    &   % Trace comparison
    &   % HeartBeating
       % SLO checks 
    
    \\  
    \hline

    \cite{gan2019leveraging, zhou2019latent} &
    &  % Log-based
    \textbullet &   % Distributed Tracing-based
    &   % Monitoring-Based
    &   % Unsupervised learning
    \textbullet &   % Supervised learning
    &   % Reinforcement learning
    &   % Semi-supervised learning
    &   % Statistical Approach
    &   % Causal Inference
    &   % Trace comparison
    &   % HeartBeating
     % SLO checks 
    \\  
    \hline

    \cite{wang2020workflow, chen2020framework, meng2021detecting} &
    &  % Log-based
    \textbullet &   % Distributed Tracing-based
    &   % Monitoring-Based
    &   % Unsupervised learning
    &   % Supervised learning
    &   % Reinforcement learning
    &   % Semi-supervised learning
    &   % Statistical Approach
    &   % Causal Inference
    \textbullet &   % Trace comparison
    &   % HeartBeating
     % SLO checks 
    \\  
    \hline
    
\end{tabularx}
\FloatBarrier
\end{table}
```

---

### Updated

[image]

I edited the table as suggested by @Zarko. Is it possible to decrease the height of the rows of the articles? The height seems too much to me and makes the table run out of the margins of the page.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\small Monitoring-Based}    % from makecell
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {Q[l, wd=11em] | *{3}{X[c]} | *{9}{X[c]}},
             colsep = 3pt,
             row{1} = {font=\small\bfseries\linespread{0,84}\selectfont, c, m},
             row{2} = {cmd=\rotcell, font=\small\linespread{0,84}\selectfont, rowsep=0pt}
            }
Paper(s)
    &   \SetCell[c=3]{c, m}    {Data\\ Sources}
        &   &   &   \SetCell[c=9]{c, m}   Technique
                    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &                  \\
    &   Log-based
        &   Distributed Tracing-based
            &   Monitoring-Based
                &   {Unsupervised\\ learning}
                    &   Supervised learning
                        &   Reinforcement learning
                            &   Semi-supervised learning
                                &   Statistical Approach
                                    &   Causal Inference
                                        &   Trace comparison
                                            &   Heart Beating
                                                &   SLO checks  \\
    
    \cite{liu2020unsupervised, nedelkoski2019anomaly, vallis2014novel, pahl2018all, jin2020anomaly, bogatinovski2020self} &
    &  % Log-based
    \textbullet &   % Distributed Tracing-based
    &   % Monitoring-Based
    \textbullet &   % Unsupervised learning
    &   % Supervised learning
    &   % Reinforcement learning
    &   % Semi-supervised learning
    &   % Statistical Approach
    &   % Causal Inference
    &   % Trace comparison
    &   % HeartBeating
       % SLO checks 
    
    \\  
    

    \cite{gan2019leveraging, zhou2019latent} &
    &  % Log-based
    \textbullet &   % Distributed Tracing-based
    &   % Monitoring-Based
    &   % Unsupervised learning
    \textbullet &   % Supervised learning
    &   % Reinforcement learning
    &   % Semi-supervised learning
    &   % Statistical Approach
    &   % Causal Inference
    &   % Trace comparison
    &   % HeartBeating
     % SLO checks 
    \\  
    

    \cite{wang2020workflow, chen2020framework, meng2021detecting} &
    &  % Log-based
    \textbullet &   % Distributed Tracing-based
    &   % Monitoring-Based
    &   % Unsupervised learning
    &   % Supervised learning
    &   % Reinforcement learning
    &   % Semi-supervised learning
    &   % Statistical Approach
    &   % Causal Inference
    \textbullet &   % Trace comparison
    &   % HeartBeating
     % SLO checks 
    \\  
    
    
    \cite{li2021microservice} &
    &  % Log-based
    \textbullet &   % Distributed Tracing-based
    &   % Monitoring-Based
    &   % Unsupervised learning
    &   % Supervised learning
    &   % Reinforcement learning
    \textbullet &   % Semi-supervised learning
    &   % Statistical Approach
    &   % Causal Inference
    &   % Trace comparison
    &   % HeartBeating
     % SLO checks 
    \\  
    
    
    \cite{chow2014mystery} &
    &  % Log-based
    \textbullet &   % Distributed Tracing-based
    &   % Monitoring-Based
    &   % Unsupervised learning
    &   % Supervised learning
    &   % Reinforcement learning
    &   % Semi-supervised learning
    &   % Statistical Approach
    \textbullet &   % Causal Inference
    &   % Trace comparison
    &   % HeartBeating
     % SLO checks 
    \\  
    
    
    \cite{belhadi2021reinforcement} &
    &  % Log-based
    \textbullet &   % Distributed Tracing-based
    &   % Monitoring-Based
    &   % Unsupervised learning
    &   % Supervised learning
    \textbullet &   % Reinforcement learning
    &   % Semi-supervised learning
    &   % Statistical Approach
    &   % Causal Inference
    &   % Trace comparison
    &   % HeartBeating
     % SLO checks 
    \\  
    
    
    \cite{sharma2013cloudpd, zhang2016taskinsight, xu2018unsupervised, gulenko2018detecting, mariani2018localizing, wu2020microrca, wu2020performance, wang2018cloudranger} &
    &  % Log-based
    &   % Distributed Tracing-based
    \textbullet &   % Monitoring-Based
    \textbullet &   % Unsupervised learning
    &   % Supervised learning
    &   % Reinforcement learning
    &   % Semi-supervised learning
    &   % Statistical Approach
    &   % Causal Inference
    &   % Trace comparison
    &   % HeartBeating
     % SLO checks 
    \\  
    
    
    \cite{sauvanaud2018anomaly, liu2015opprentice, du2018anomaly, mariani2020predicting, samir2019dla} &
    &  % Log-based
    &   % Distributed Tracing-based
    \textbullet &   % Monitoring-Based
    &   % Unsupervised learning
    \textbullet &   % Supervised learning
    &   % Reinforcement learning
    &   % Semi-supervised learning
    &   % Statistical Approach
    &   % Causal Inference
    &   % Trace comparison
    &   % HeartBeating
     % SLO checks 
    \\  
    
    
    \cite{magalhaes2010detection, peiris2014pad, abdelrahman2016detection, kang2012dapa, yang2007anomaly, wang2013energy, ahad2015toward, nguyen2013fchain, tan2012prepare, gu2009online} &
    &  % Log-based
    &   % Distributed Tracing-based
    \textbullet &   % Monitoring-Based
    &   % Unsupervised learning
    &   % Supervised learning
    &   % Reinforcement learning
    &   % Semi-supervised learning
    \textbullet &   % Statistical Approach
    &   % Causal Inference
    &   % Trace comparison
    &   % HeartBeating
     % SLO checks 
    \\  
    
    
    \cite{chen2014causeinfer, chen2016causeinfer, shan2019diagnosis, lin2018microscope} &
    &  % Log-based
    &   % Distributed Tracing-based
    \textbullet &   % Monitoring-Based
    &   % Unsupervised learning
    &   % Supervised learning
    &   % Reinforcement learning
    &   % Semi-supervised learning
    &   % Statistical Approach
    &   % Causal Inference
    &   % Trace comparison
    &   % HeartBeating
    \textbullet  % SLO checks 
    \\  
    
    
    \cite{zang2018fault} &
    &  % Log-based
    &   % Distributed Tracing-based
    \textbullet &   % Monitoring-Based
    &   % Unsupervised learning
    &   % Supervised learning
    &   % Reinforcement learning
    &   % Semi-supervised learning
    &   % Statistical Approach
    &   % Causal Inference
    &   % Trace comparison
    \textbullet  &   % HeartBeating
    % SLO checks 
    \\  
    
    
    \cite{du2017deeplog, yagoub2018equipment, liang2007failure, zhang2016automated, brown2018recurrent, meng2019loganomaly, zhang2019robust, nandi2016anomaly, jia2017logsed, fu2009execution} &
    \textbullet &  % Log-based
    &   % Distributed Tracing-based
    &   % Monitoring-Based
    \textbullet &   % Unsupervised learning
    &   % Supervised learning
    &   % Reinforcement learning
    &   % Semi-supervised learning
    &   % Statistical Approach
    &   % Causal Inference
    &   % Trace comparison
    &   % HeartBeating
    % SLO checks 
    \\  
    

    \cite{fronza2013failure} &
    \textbullet &  % Log-based
    &   % Distributed Tracing-based
    &   % Monitoring-Based
    &   % Unsupervised learning
    \textbullet &   % Supervised learning
    &   % Reinforcement learning
    &   % Semi-supervised learning
    &   % Statistical Approach
    &   % Causal Inference
    &   % Trace comparison
    &   % HeartBeating
    % SLO checks 
    \\  
    
    
    \cite{fu2009execution} &
    \textbullet &  % Log-based
    &   % Distributed Tracing-based
    &   % Monitoring-Based
    \textbullet &   % Unsupervised learning
    \textbullet &   % Supervised learning
    &   % Reinforcement learning
    &   % Semi-supervised learning
    &   % Statistical Approach
    &   % Causal Inference
    &   % Trace comparison
    &   % HeartBeating
    % SLO checks 
    \\  
    

   \cite{yang2021semi} &
    \textbullet &  % Log-based
    &   % Distributed Tracing-based
    &   % Monitoring-Based
    &   % Unsupervised learning
    &   % Supervised learning
    &   % Reinforcement learning
    \textbullet &   % Semi-supervised learning
    &   % Statistical Approach
    &   % Causal Inference
    &   % Trace comparison
    &   % HeartBeating
    % SLO checks 
    \\  
    

    \cite{salfner2007using, beschastnikh2014inferring} &
    \textbullet &  % Log-based
    &   % Distributed Tracing-based
    &   % Monitoring-Based
    &   % Unsupervised learning
    &   % Supervised learning
    &   % Reinforcement learning
    &   % Semi-supervised learning
    \textbullet &   % Statistical Approach
    &   % Causal Inference
    &   % Trace comparison
    &   % HeartBeating
    % SLO checks 
    \\  
    
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you searched this site? These questions come up with some regularity …

Comment: Please add the code, which comes beforehand, and at the end. It would be helpful, if you delete most table columns, as their content doesn't add to the problems you describe: scrolling will be easier for all of us.

Comment: Welcome! Hmm: 1. it is (you use `\textwidth`); 2. they are (alt least all the `C` columns); 3. use `\begin{table}[p]`. Why the `\FloatBarrier` *inside* a float?

Comment: I edited the code.
1. But the \textwidth and C are not working. The columns are not all the same size. As you can see from the image.  3. the FloatBarrier is for fixing the table at one position in the article.

Comment: With tabularx, only the X columns (and derivatives) are adjusted.  With tabular* the gaps between the columns are adjusted.

Comment: If you edited and it fixed your problem then please accept the answer. If following that you have another question you should start a new question, to which the community will give another answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With use `tabularray`, `rotating` and `makecell` packages, rotated text is, where is necessary, in two lines.

**Edit:**
Table code is extended with rows provided in edited question. With added rows table stil can be fitted on one page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\small Monitoring-Based}    % from makecell
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {Q[l, m, wd=11em] | *{3}{X[c]} | *{9}{X[c]}},
             colsep = 3pt,
             row{1} = {font=\small\bfseries\linespread{0,84}\selectfont, c, m},
             row{2} = {cmd=\rotcell, font=\small\linespread{0,84}\selectfont, rowsep=0pt}
            }
Paper(s)
    &   \SetCell[c=3]{c, m}    {Data\\ Sources}
        &   &   &   \SetCell[c=9]{c, m}   Technique
                    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &                  \\
    &   Log-based
        &   Distributed Tracing-based
            &   Monitoring-Based
                &   {Unsupervised\\ learning}
                    &   Supervised learning
                        &   Reinforcement learning
                            &   Semi-supervised learning
                                &   Statistical Approach
                                    &   Causal Inference
                                        &   Trace comparison
                                            &   Heart Beating
                                                &   SLO checks  \\
\cite{liu2020unsupervised, nedelkoski2019anomaly, vallis2014novel, pahl2018all, jin2020anomaly, bogatinovski2020self}
    & \textbullet
        &   &   & \textbullet
                    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &               \\
\cite{gan2019leveraging, zhou2019latent} 
    &   & \textbullet
            &   & \textbullet
                    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &               \\
\cite{wang2020workflow, chen2020framework, meng2021detecting}
    &   & \textbullet
            &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & \textbullet
                                            &   &               \\
% data from added rows in question
\cite{li2021microservice} &
    &  \textbullet 
        &   &   &   &   & \textbullet 
                            &   &   &   &   &   &               \\
\cite{chow2014mystery} 
    &   & \textbullet 
            &   &   &   &   &   &   & \textbullet 
                                        &   &   &               \\
\cite{belhadi2021reinforcement} 
    &   & \textbullet 
            &   &   &   & \textbullet 
                            &   &   &   &   &   &               \\
\cite{sharma2013cloudpd, zhang2016taskinsight, xu2018unsupervised, gulenko2018detecting, mariani2018localizing, wu2020microrca, wu2020performance, wang2018cloudranger} 
    &   &   & \textbullet 
                & \textbullet 
                    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &               \\
\cite{sauvanaud2018anomaly, liu2015opprentice, du2018anomaly, mariani2020predicting, samir2019dla}
    &   &   & \textbullet 
                &   & \textbullet 
                        &   &   &   &   &   &   &               \\
\cite{magalhaes2010detection, peiris2014pad, abdelrahman2016detection, kang2012dapa, yang2007anomaly, wang2013energy, ahad2015toward, nguyen2013fchain, tan2012prepare, gu2009online} 
    &   &   & \textbullet
                &   &   &   &   & \textbullet 
                                    &   &   &   &               \\
\cite{chen2014causeinfer, chen2016causeinfer, shan2019diagnosis, lin2018microscope} 
    &   &   & \textbullet 
                &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & \textbullet   \\
\cite{zang2018fault} 
    &   &   & \textbullet 
                &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & \textbullet  
                                                &               \\
\cite{du2017deeplog, yagoub2018equipment, liang2007failure, zhang2016automated, brown2018recurrent, meng2019loganomaly, zhang2019robust, nandi2016anomaly, jia2017logsed, fu2009execution} 
    & \textbullet 
        &   &   & \textbullet 
                    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &               \\
\cite{fronza2013failure} 
    & \textbullet 
        &   &   &   & \textbullet 
                        &   &   &   &   &   &   &               \\
\cite{fu2009execution} 
    & \textbullet 
        &   &   & \textbullet 
                    & \textbullet 
                        &   &   &   &   &   &   &               \\
\cite{yang2021semi} 
    & \textbullet 
        &   &   &   &   &   & \textbullet 
                                &   &   &   &   &               \\
\cite{salfner2007using, beschastnikh2014inferring} 
    & \textbullet 
        &   &   &   &   &   &   & \textbullet 
                                    &   &   &   &               \\

\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}

Paper(s)    
    &   \SetCell[c=3]{c, m}    {Data\\ Sources}
        &   &   &   \SetCell[c=9]{c, m}   Technique                
                    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &              \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

**Note:**

- All columns except first are of equal width.
- Table width is equal to `\textwidth`.
- Table can easily fit in one page even width rows added in edited question
- We haven't any information about your document page layout, so it is unknown how much space is available for table. Now is considered MWE (which apparently is based on this answer) in edited question.
- Please, in your eventually new questions always provide MWE )Minimal Working Example=, a complete small document, which show your problem

Comment: thank you very much for the reply, it helped me a lot. I have edited the initial post with the result. Is it possible to decrease the height of the rows of the articles? The height seems too much to me and makes the table run out of the margins of the page.

Comment: @user2989745, you not show the code, by which you produce shoed table, so I don't know what you doing. Please, be so kind and add the code by which you generate showed result. You change something in my code.

Comment: Post edited, I added the code.

Comment: @user2989745, no just code fragment. Please provide complete small document, which we can compiled as it is. Your code fragment using in my MWE gives result as I showed in answer, not what you provide in edited answer.

Comment: Post edited with a complete small document.

Comment: @user2989745, MWE, provided in edited question works fine. It occupy about half page. No problems on my side. I will extend my answer with rows, which are now known, ASAP.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. Everything worked out fine :)

Answer (score 1):

On top of Zarko's answer, you might opt for reduced number lines as well use  custom rules from `booktabs`. The table is big. One suggestion is to typeset the table in a landscape environment. Another is to add alternating colours and remove multiple horizontal lines, which might be even more preferable if you want to increase height of each row.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{geometry}   % for changing a document layout
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xcolor}
    \colorlet{bgodd}{black!10}
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}       % for dummy text


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[ht]
        % from makecell
        \settowidth\rotheadsize{\small Monitoring-Based}
        \begin{tblr}{
                colspec = {Q[l, wd=5cm] *{3}{X[c]} *{9}{X[c]}},
                vline{2-Y} = {2-Z}{dotted},
                vline{2,5} = {2-Z}{solid, \lightrulewidth},   % \lightrulewidth is defined in booktabs
                rows = {abovesep=2pt, belowsep=2pt},
                row{odd} = {bg=bgodd},
                colsep = 2pt,
                row{1} = {
                    font=\bfseries, %\linespread{0.84}\selectfont,
                    c, m,
                },
                row{2} = {
                      cmd=\rotcell,
                    rowsep=0pt
                },
            }
            \toprule
            \SetRow{bg=white}
            Paper(s) &
            \SetCell[c=3]{c, m} {Data\\ Sources} &&&
                \SetCell[c=9]{c, m} Technique &&&&&&&& \\
            \midrule
            & Log-based
                & Distributed Tracing-based
                & Monitoring-Based
                & {Unsupervised\\ learning}
                & Supervised learning
                & Reinforcement learning
                & Semi-supervised learning
                & Statistical Approach
                & Causal Inference
                & Trace comparison
                & Heart Beating
                & SLO checks \\
            \midrule
            \cite{liu2020unsupervised, nedelkoski2019anomaly, vallis2014novel, pahl2018all, jin2020anomaly, bogatinovski2020self} &
            &  % Log-based
            \textbullet &   % Distributed Tracing-based
            &   % Monitoring-Based
            \textbullet &   % Unsupervised learning
            &   % Supervised learning
            &   % Reinforcement learning
            &   % Semi-supervised learning
            &   % Statistical Approach
            &   % Causal Inference
            &   % Trace comparison
            &   % HeartBeating
               % SLO checks 
            \\
            \cite{gan2019leveraging, zhou2019latent} &
            &  % Log-based
            \textbullet &   % Distributed Tracing-based
            &   % Monitoring-Based
            &   % Unsupervised learning
            \textbullet &   % Supervised learning
            &   % Reinforcement learning
            &   % Semi-supervised learning
            &   % Statistical Approach
            &   % Causal Inference
            &   % Trace comparison
            &   % HeartBeating
             % SLO checks 
            \\
            \cite{wang2020workflow, chen2020framework, meng2021detecting} &
            &  % Log-based
            \textbullet &   % Distributed Tracing-based
            &   % Monitoring-Based
            &   % Unsupervised learning
            &   % Supervised learning
            &   % Reinforcement learning
            &   % Semi-supervised learning
            &   % Statistical Approach
            &   % Causal Inference
            \textbullet &   % Trace comparison
            &   % HeartBeating
             % SLO checks 
            \\
            \cite{li2021microservice} &
            &  % Log-based
            \textbullet &   % Distributed Tracing-based
            &   % Monitoring-Based
            &   % Unsupervised learning
            &   % Supervised learning
            &   % Reinforcement learning
            \textbullet &   % Semi-supervised learning
            &   % Statistical Approach
            &   % Causal Inference
            &   % Trace comparison
            &   % HeartBeating
             % SLO checks 
            \\
            \cite{chow2014mystery} &
            &  % Log-based
            \textbullet &   % Distributed Tracing-based
            &   % Monitoring-Based
            &   % Unsupervised learning
            &   % Supervised learning
            &   % Reinforcement learning
            &   % Semi-supervised learning
            &   % Statistical Approach
            \textbullet &   % Causal Inference
            &   % Trace comparison
            &   % HeartBeating
             % SLO checks 
            \\
            \cite{belhadi2021reinforcement} &
            &  % Log-based
            \textbullet &   % Distributed Tracing-based
            &   % Monitoring-Based
            &   % Unsupervised learning
            &   % Supervised learning
            \textbullet &   % Reinforcement learning
            &   % Semi-supervised learning
            &   % Statistical Approach
            &   % Causal Inference
            &   % Trace comparison
            &   % HeartBeating
             % SLO checks 
            \\
            \cite{sharma2013cloudpd, zhang2016taskinsight, xu2018unsupervised, gulenko2018detecting, mariani2018localizing, wu2020microrca, wu2020performance, wang2018cloudranger} &
            &  % Log-based
            &   % Distributed Tracing-based
            \textbullet &   % Monitoring-Based
            \textbullet &   % Unsupervised learning
            &   % Supervised learning
            &   % Reinforcement learning
            &   % Semi-supervised learning
            &   % Statistical Approach
            &   % Causal Inference
            &   % Trace comparison
            &   % HeartBeating
             % SLO checks 
            \\
            \cite{sauvanaud2018anomaly, liu2015opprentice, du2018anomaly, mariani2020predicting, samir2019dla} &
            &  % Log-based
            &   % Distributed Tracing-based
            \textbullet &   % Monitoring-Based
            &   % Unsupervised learning
            \textbullet &   % Supervised learning
            &   % Reinforcement learning
            &   % Semi-supervised learning
            &   % Statistical Approach
            &   % Causal Inference
            &   % Trace comparison
            &   % HeartBeating
             % SLO checks 
            \\
            \cite{magalhaes2010detection, peiris2014pad, abdelrahman2016detection, kang2012dapa, yang2007anomaly, wang2013energy, ahad2015toward, nguyen2013fchain, tan2012prepare, gu2009online} &
            &  % Log-based
            &   % Distributed Tracing-based
            \textbullet &   % Monitoring-Based
            &   % Unsupervised learning
            &   % Supervised learning
            &   % Reinforcement learning
            &   % Semi-supervised learning
            \textbullet &   % Statistical Approach
            &   % Causal Inference
            &   % Trace comparison
            &   % HeartBeating
             % SLO checks 
            \\
            \cite{chen2014causeinfer, chen2016causeinfer, shan2019diagnosis, lin2018microscope} &
            &  % Log-based
            &   % Distributed Tracing-based
            \textbullet &   % Monitoring-Based
            &   % Unsupervised learning
            &   % Supervised learning
            &   % Reinforcement learning
            &   % Semi-supervised learning
            &   % Statistical Approach
            &   % Causal Inference
            &   % Trace comparison
            &   % HeartBeating
            \textbullet  % SLO checks 
            \\
            \cite{zang2018fault} &
            &  % Log-based
            &   % Distributed Tracing-based
            \textbullet &   % Monitoring-Based
            &   % Unsupervised learning
            &   % Supervised learning
            &   % Reinforcement learning
            &   % Semi-supervised learning
            &   % Statistical Approach
            &   % Causal Inference
            &   % Trace comparison
            \textbullet  &   % HeartBeating
            % SLO checks 
            \\
            \cite{du2017deeplog, yagoub2018equipment, liang2007failure, zhang2016automated, brown2018recurrent, meng2019loganomaly, zhang2019robust, nandi2016anomaly, jia2017logsed, fu2009execution} &
            \textbullet &  % Log-based
            &   % Distributed Tracing-based
            &   % Monitoring-Based
            \textbullet &   % Unsupervised learning
            &   % Supervised learning
            &   % Reinforcement learning
            &   % Semi-supervised learning
            &   % Statistical Approach
            &   % Causal Inference
            &   % Trace comparison
            &   % HeartBeating
            % SLO checks 
            \\
            \cite{fronza2013failure} &
            \textbullet &  % Log-based
            &   % Distributed Tracing-based
            &   % Monitoring-Based
            &   % Unsupervised learning
            \textbullet &   % Supervised learning
            &   % Reinforcement learning
            &   % Semi-supervised learning
            &   % Statistical Approach
            &   % Causal Inference
            &   % Trace comparison
            &   % HeartBeating
            % SLO checks 
            \\
            \cite{fu2009execution} &
            \textbullet &  % Log-based
            &   % Distributed Tracing-based
            &   % Monitoring-Based
            \textbullet &   % Unsupervised learning
            \textbullet &   % Supervised learning
            &   % Reinforcement learning
            &   % Semi-supervised learning
            &   % Statistical Approach
            &   % Causal Inference
            &   % Trace comparison
            &   % HeartBeating
            % SLO checks 
            \\
           \cite{yang2021semi} &
            \textbullet &  % Log-based
            &   % Distributed Tracing-based
            &   % Monitoring-Based
            &   % Unsupervised learning
            &   % Supervised learning
            &   % Reinforcement learning
            \textbullet &   % Semi-supervised learning
            &   % Statistical Approach
            &   % Causal Inference
            &   % Trace comparison
            &   % HeartBeating
            % SLO checks 
            \\
            \cite{salfner2007using, beschastnikh2014inferring} &
            \textbullet &  % Log-based
            &   % Distributed Tracing-based
            &   % Monitoring-Based
            &   % Unsupervised learning
            &   % Supervised learning
            &   % Reinforcement learning
            &   % Semi-supervised learning
            \textbullet &   % Statistical Approach
            &   % Causal Inference
            &   % Trace comparison
            &   % HeartBeating
            % SLO checks 
            \\
            \midrule
        \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The table is on the second page. I added two paragraphs one before and one after the table to demonstrate `landscape` environment would typeset its content on a separate page. I forgot to mention that, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It took too long to compile. It is giving an error: Missing number treated as zero.

Comment: The problem was the version of the tabular. I was using the wrong version. It works fine!  Thanks for sharing and the tips.